# Firestore emulator - "Use of ternary operator not allowed."

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-cli

I have updated my firebase-tools library and emulator to the latest version but I keep getting the error in the title when trying to run my rules

Full error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error compiling rules:
Use of ternary operator not allowed.
```

As an example, it shows this error on the following code:

```
function test(val) {
  return val ? 1 : 2;
}
```

This should work as per the latest [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules) and the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language#building_conditions). Is the emulator not yet supporting the ternary operator?

Comment: If the emulator isn't working the way you expect, you should file an issue on its GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

While this feature is already available in the console Rules Playground and in production, this feature is planned to be in the next release of the emulators / CLI (>7.16.1).

It's unfortunate that there is a discrepancy in this case. Thanks for bringing it up though!

Comment: Yep my bug request got promptly addressed :)